# data.frame structure fubar: structure says most character, printing says only some

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

I'm using `sqldf` to subset an enormous file. The following command gives me a data.frame of 100 rows and 42 columns.

```
first <- read.csv.sql("first.txt", sep = " ", header = TRUE, row.names = FALSE,
        sql = "SELECT * FROM file WHERE n = '\"n63\"' AND ratio = 1 AND r_name = '\"r1\"' AND method = '\"nearest\"' AND variables = 10")
```

The structure of the object is

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  42 variables:
 $ test_before       : chr  "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" ...
 $ test_after        : chr  "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" "TRUE" ...
 $ meanPSmatchRATIO  : chr  "1.54845330373635" "1.16857102212364" "1.25330045961256" "1.8011651466717" ...
snipped intervening normally printed columns
 $ PSdiff_DIFF       : chr  "-0.0103938442562762" "-0.00935228868105753" "-0.00947571480267878" 
snipped intervening normally printed columns
 $ nUNMATCHt         : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ caliper           : chr  "\"no\"" "\"no\"" "\"no\"" "\"no\"" ...
 $ method            : chr  "\"nearest\"" "\"nearest\"" "\"nearest\"" "\"nearest\"" ...
 $ r_name            : chr  "\"r1\"" "\"r1\"" "\"r1\"" "\"r1\"" ...
 $ ratio             : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ n                 : chr  "\"n63\"" "\"n63\"" "\"n63\"" "\"n63\"" ...
 $ variables         : int  10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 ...
```

Now, based on this you would expect that when I print the data.frame, all columns (except those `int` will be character (enclosed in "")). But you would be wrong!

```
  test_before test_after meanPSmatchRATIO del-  nUNMATCHt caliper    method r_name ratio     n variables
1        TRUE       TRUE 1.54845330373635 eted          0    "no" "nearest"   "r1"     1 "n63"        10
2        TRUE       TRUE 1.16857102212364 ...           0    "no" "nearest"   "r1"     1 "n63"        10
3        TRUE       TRUE 1.25330045961256 ...           0    "no" "nearest"   "r1"     1 "n63"        10
4        TRUE       TRUE  1.8011651466717 ...t          0    "no" "nearest"   "r1"     1 "n63"        10
```

Notice that only the last few columns are "character". I'm a bit lost at what's going on. Can someone explain?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Not quoting characters seems normal to me when displaying data frames at the console. It will quote the elements if I inspect a single column, but not the whole data frame.

Comment: The `str` claims that most of the columns are character. Including caliper, method, r_name and n. Yet only the aforementioned columns get printed with a `"`, all others behave as factor or numeric (or as is the case for first two columns, logical).

Comment: Those columns have embedded `"`. The first element of `caliper` is `"\"no\""`!

Comment: I edited the output of str(...)  so at least the next reader can immediately see the important bits. (A similar operation on the object would have made this a more "minimal" example when it was printed.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks fine to me.  `print.data.frame` doesn't usually print quotes for character columns, but those last few columns have embedded quotes, so that's why they *appear* "quoted" by default.

```
Data <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=as.character(1:5),
  z=letters[1:5], q=paste("\"",letters[1:5],"\"",sep=""))
print(Data)  # default print
#   x y z   q
# 1 1 1 a "a"
# 2 2 2 b "b"
# 3 3 3 c "c"
# 4 4 4 d "d"
# 5 5 5 e "e"
print(Data, quote=TRUE)  # show embedded quotes
#     x   y   z       q
# 1 "1" "1" "a" "\"a\""
# 2 "2" "2" "b" "\"b\""
# 3 "3" "3" "c" "\"c\""
# 4 "4" "4" "d" "\"d\""
# 5 "5" "5" "e" "\"e\""
```

Answer (score 2):

You are seeing the default behaviour of the `print` method for data frame objects. See `?print.data.frame`, which has:

```
   quote: logical, indicating whether or not entries should be printed
          with surrounding quotes.
```

so if you want the printed object to be quoted, use `quote = TRUE`. E.g.:

```
> dat <- data.frame(X = c("A","B"), Y = c("1","2"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> dat
  X Y
1 A 1
2 B 2
> dat[,1] ## not using the data frame print method...
[1] "A" "B"
> print(dat, quote = TRUE)
    X   Y
1 "A" "1"
2 "B" "2"
```

**Edit:** regarding @Roman's comment, the columns printing *with* quotes contain *embedded* quotes in the data. For example, the first element of `caliper` is `"\"no\""`, so it is the embedded quotes that are being printed and thus is fully consistent with the default behaviour of `print.data.frame()`.